# How to do correct inner join over this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.quantity, p.price, pd.name, pd.description
FROM product AS p
INNER JOIN product_description AS pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
WHERE p.product_id = 1 AND pd.landuage_id = 5
```

In this query, only one condition exists, `p.product_id` in this case, but the other condition `pd.landuage_id` does not exist. I want the request to be executed, whether it exists. How to do it ?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The "request" is executed.  Your issue is that you don't like the results.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't forget to Accept (click the green check box) and Upvote (click the upward pointing arrow) helpful answers to your questions.

Comment: @O.Jones How to click upvote, when i don't have enoufh reputation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible duplicate, but right answer is:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.quantity, p.price, pd.name, pd.description
FROM product p 
LEFT JOIN product_description pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id AND pd.language_id = 5
WHERE p.product_id = 1;
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it! Thank u !